# Subclassed UITableViewController with storyboard results in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier being nil

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

I've got a storyboard that uses a segue to instantiate a view controller.  I changed the header file for that view controller so that it is a subclass UITableViewController.  Inside the tableview in the storyboard, I have setup a prototype cell with "dynamic prototypes", and given it a unique identifier.

When my controller gets instantiated, the table view object is instantiated, and to prove that I am getting the right TableView, I assigned a unique tag for it and can see it is the correct TableView in the console.  However, when my code does:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"uniqueIdentifier"];
```

The cell is nil...  Why, oh why?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should create it if its null so that you can reuse it later ?

```
   UITableViewCell *cell = 
                       [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"uniqueIdentifier"];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
           initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"uniqueIdentifier"];
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried that.  It still is nil every time and so it always gets recreated.

Comment: @patrick cell will get reused only if you scroll them up out of the screen, otherwise they are nil to begin with